# How can I programmatically display a dataTip in a Flex 3 chart (without hovering with the mouse)?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, charts

I would like to show a dataTip on a flex chart by setting the selectedIndex property of the AreaSeries.  For instance, if selectedIndex = 2, then a dataTip appears over the third item in the series.  Is this possible in Flex 3.5?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be trivial, but you can listen to the 'change' event which should fire whenever the selectedIndex changes.

Then use the PopUpManager to create your tooltip.  You'll have to write your own code to figure out where to position the tooltip.